# How to remove duplicate words from a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

I have a vector with duplicate words stored in it. How can I remove the duplicates? Example: if the vector has `apple, orange, pear, apple, grape, grape`, I want it to then just have `apple, orange, pear, grape`. I tried using `unique` but it didn't work. Did I do it wrongly?

Comment: Post the code that didn't work, we can't extrapolate your erroneous code from your text

Comment: [Sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the vector, then [remove consecutive duplicates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Answer (score 4):

Use std::sort and erase:

```
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );
v.erase( std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

If you want to save the order of elements you can use `std::remove_if` and `std::set` for saving unique elements:

```
template <typename T>
void remove_dups_from_vector( std::vector<T> &v )
{
    std::set<T> unique_elements;
    v.erase( std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
        [&]( const T &value ) {
            return !unique_elements.insert(value).second;
        } )
        , v.end( ) );
}
```

Comment: is it possible without sorting? I'm reading something from  a file and i want to keep track of the order they appear

Comment: Yep. You can you `std::remove_if` and `std::set` for saving unique elements. Updated answer.